# Error with Auth0 and Graphql - TypeError: Cannot read property 'publicKey' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, auth0, express-graphql

I am currently trying to setup authentication for Graphql via Auth0. The issue we are facing is inside our authenticate Mutation returning the error

```
\validateAndParseIdToken.js:25
      jwt.verify(idToken, key.publicKey, {
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'publicKey' of undefined
```

We have verified the idToken is being passed in for decoding by the validateAndParseIdToken function

```
validateAndParseIdToken.js

const jwksClient = require('jwks-rsa')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const jwks = jwksClient({
  cache: true,
  rateLimit: true,
  jwksRequestsPerMinute: 1,
  jwksUri: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json`
})

const validateAndParseIdToken = (idToken) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const { header, payload} = jwt.decode(idToken, {complete: true})
  if (!header || !header.kid || !payload) reject(new Error('Invalid Token'))
  jwks.getSigningKey(header.kid, (err, key) => {
    if (err) reject(new Error('Error getting signing key: ' + err.message))
    jwt.verify(idToken, key.publicKey, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) reject('jwt verify error: ' + err.message)
      resolve(decoded)
    })
  })
})

module.exports = validateAndParseIdToken
```

```
authenticate mutation -

const Mutation = {
  async authenticate(parent, { idToken }, ctx, info) {
    let userToken = null
    try {
      userToken = await validateAndParseIdToken(idToken)
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err.message)
    }
    const auth0id = userToken.sub.split('|')[1]
    let user = await ctx.prisma.query.user({ where: { auth0id } }, info)
    if (!user) {
      user = createPrismaUser(ctx, userToken)
    }
    return user
  },
```

The expect flow would be to check an idToken, if it is valid then check if a user exists in our DB for that user, if not then create that user.

Comment: Try `key.publicRsaKey`.

Answer (score 0):

A late reply...

Had the same issue deploying ApolloServer to Heroku.

Adding the AUTH0_DOMAIN="xxx" and API_IDENTIFIER="xxx" to the Heroku Config Vars list worked.(i.e. use the values you would have in the local .env file)